# Prove that $\frac{1}{n}S_n\to -1$ a. s. and $\frac{1}{n}E[S_n]\to 0$

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent random variables such that$$P(X_n=n^2)=\frac{1}{n^2}=1-P(X_n=-1) \text{ for all } n$$
> Show that  for $S_n=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}X_k$, we have $\frac{1}{n}E(S_n)\to 0$ for all $n$ but $\frac{1}{n}S_n\to -1$ almost surely as $n\to \infty$

**Attempt**

Using Borel-Cantelli, we have $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}P(X_n=n^{2})=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$, which implies the probability of $X_n=n^2$ is $0$ for infinitely many $n$. That means $X_n=-1$ for sufficient $n$ with probability $1$. This implies that $$S_n=\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k \to -1$$ almost surely.

Is this correct and what about $\frac{1}{n}E(S_n)\to 0$. And how does this not contradict the law of large numbers?

Comment: You might want to expand on why you think this contradicts the law of large numbers. For the first part, what is $E(X_n)$? If you can use linearity of expectation for countable variables, the result follows pretty closely.

Comment: I know that:$$E\left(S_n\right)=E\left(\frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2+\cdots + X_n)\right)=\frac{1}{n}(E(X_1)+\cdots + E(X_n))$$ But what is $E(X_i)$?

Comment: What are the possible values of $X_n$? And what are the probabilities associated with each of those possible values?

Comment: $i^2$ and $-1$?, probabilities are given above

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} k^2\cdot P(X_k=k^2)-1\cdot P(X_k=-1)=\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2} \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} 0$$?

Comment: Yes; my question was rhetorical, but as long as you are allowed to use countable linearity of expectation, that should suffice.

Comment: Is my attempt in the question correct? Borel-Cantelli should do the job, right?

Comment: Yes, although your wording is a little funny. I would probably put it as "the probability that $X_n = n^2$ for infinitely many $n$ is zero."